# How does Xamarin MVVMCross tie in with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm fairly new to Xamarin development, but I've started doing some experiments with Xamarin.Forms and I'm really liking it.

Now, I've discovered MVVMCross, and it sounds interesting for developing apps that have separated UIs for each platform, but I'm trying to find *updated* information regarding how (and if / why) it may tie in with Xamarin.Forms ([mvvm's docs has a page for this](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/xamarinforms), but it's empty ATM).

Is there any currently-relevant information I'm not being able to find? (all results I'm finding seem to be too old and not really helpful, please correct me if my google-fu is just not strong enough)

Comment: OK, I've found some results, mainly https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2017/03/26/xamarin-forms-application-with-mvvmcross/ and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CristianChereches.XamarinFormswithMvvmCrossSolutionTemplate, but I'm still not getting the full picture so I won't kill the question.

Comment: Have you considered other MVVM libraries such as Xamarin.Forms.Labs which specifically target Xamarin.Forms? The original intent of MvvmCross was to build a MVVM framework that allows you to share all logic in-between Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. Conclusively, I think you should consider other frameworks. Although, if you want to use MvvmCross, you can investigate their [source code for Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross-Forms).

Comment: Just a side note: avoid using Xamarin.Forms.Labs as it's a dead library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, for lack of better replies. From [this blog post](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2017/03/26/xamarin-forms-application-with-mvvmcross/):

> (...) it is crucial to understand that neither MvvmCross nor Xamarin.Forms is a replacement for one another. While both of them provide infrastructure modules that help developers in their mobile application projects, Xamarin.Forms is a UI technology stack that enables common XAML declarative UI implementation for target platforms; MvvmCross is a framework that enforces clear distinction between the UI elements and core logic implementation. Either of them alone or together can increase the shared amount of code in cross platform projects.